# Ignore one word with regex

Tags: regex, wordpress

I know there are several similar questions already asked. But can't fix this issue with regex.

I have sentence like

> Lorem Ipsum is http://stack.com text of the http://stack.com/wp-admin
>   printing and typesetting industry.

I want to cache the word "stack.com" but not **stack.com/wp-admin**

I have tried few regex but it's not working.

```
^(?!stack.com$).*
```

Comment: @anubhava Then, if `stack.com` is followed with a comma, it won't get matched.

Comment: ok then probably: `\bstack\.com(?![/?])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `^(?!stack.com$).*` regex matches any string (even an empty one) that does not start with `stack.com`.

To match `stack.com` but not inside `stack.com/wp-admin`, you need a negative lookahead:

```
/stack\.com(?!\/wp-admin)/
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or better, with word boundaries to only match *whole* words:

```
/\bstack\.com\b(?!\/wp-admin)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/p6xROv/1)

**Details**:

- `\b` - a leading word boundary
- `stack\.com` - a literal string `stack.com` (a dot must be escaped)
- `\b` - a trailing word boundary
- `(?!\/wp-admin)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `/wp-admin` immediately to the right of the current location.

Comment: I don't think one needs a look ahead. Given above's problems on could simply check for: "stack\.com $" - special attention to the ending space char.

Comment: @blauerschluessel I think OP wants to match `stack.com` in `On stack.com, you can learn more...`. So, a word boundary with a lookahead looks viable.

Comment: Definitely, it does.

Comment: "\bstack\.com \b" - seems correct - solving above problem.

Comment: @blauerschluessel If you put  a space after `com`, you require a space to be after `com`, and you require a word char after the word boundary. Not sure it is what is necessary here.